# Add data into a column of a pivot table [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table

So basically I want to create an "appel" or a "registration" if you prefer.Into this you can add the name of the "creator" of the registration.All of that, is in my table "appel":

"id | createur | created_at  | updated_at"

To continue I have my table student where all the student are with their informations:

"id | uuid | created_at | updated_at | first_name | last_name | email_address"

I've created a pivot table named "AppelStudent" to attach everything.
Into this table I have the column "present" which is a boolean to know if the student was in the class or not.  To finish I have the column "motif" to write a text if necessary.

"id  | appel_id | student_id | present | motif"

I can create everything in my form expect the "motif", I don't find how to correctly attach the motif of the student.Like if I check the checkbox "present" of the student it won't save the motif.To be more understandable look at my code.

First this is my Appel controller

```
  public function add_appel(Request $request){
      $messages = [
          'required' => 'Le champ ":attribute" est manquant',
          'string' => ':attribute n\'est pas valide',
        ];

        $attributes = [
          'createur' => 'Createur de lappel',
          // 'motif' => 'Motif élève', Problème avec motif
        ];

        $validateData = Validator::make($request->all(), [
          'createur' => 'required | string',
          'present' => '',
        
        
         
        ], $messages, $attributes);

        if ($validateData->fails()) {
            $errors = $validateData->errors();
            foreach ($errors->all() as $message) {
              connectify('error','Erreur',$message);
            }
            return redirect("/appel/new");
        }
        else {
       
          $appel = Appel::create([
            "createur" => $request->createur, 
          ]);
          //   $appel->minorstudents()->attach($request->minorstudents, [
          //  "present" => true,
          //  "motif" => $request->input("motif")[$index]
          // ]
          // );
                    foreach($request->minorstudents as $index => $minorstudent) {
              $appel->minorstudents()->attach($request->minorstudents, [
                  "present" => true,
                  "motif" => $request->input("motif")[$index]
              ]);
          }
          // $appel->minorstudents()->attach(Minorstudent::whereNotIn("id", $request->minorstudents)->get());
          
          foreach(Minorstudent::whereNotIn("id", $request->minorstudents)->get() as $index => $minorstudent) {
              $appel->minorstudents()->attach($minorstudent, [
                  "motif" => $request->input("motif")[$index]
              ]);
            }
$appel->save();
          // $appel->minorstudents()->updateExistingPivot($request->minorstudents, ['motif' => $request->motif]);
          
          // $appel->students()->attach($request->students, [
          //  "present" => true,
          // // "motif" => $request->input('motif'),
          // // "motif" => $request->motif,
          // ]
          //               );
          // $appel->students()->attach(Student::whereNotIn("id", $request->students)->get());
          //  $appel->students()->attach(["motif" =>$request->input('motif')]);       
          // $appel->students()->syncWithPivotValues([1],['motif' => $request->motif]);   
          //  dd($appel->students()->motif = $request->motif);
          //  $appel->students()->attach($request->students);
          //  $appel->students()->updateExistingPivot($request->students, ['motif' => $request->input('motif')]);
          return redirect("/appel");
        }
    }
```

This is my moigrations pivot table

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('appel_student', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('appel_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('minorstudent_id')->constrained();
            $table->boolean('present')->default(false);
            $table->string('motif')->default('/');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

This is my form into my .blade

```
 @foreach ($students as $student)
                   <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
                      <tr>
                       
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                          {{$student->first_name}}                             //This show the informations of the student//
                            </div>
                        </td>
                       
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div class="text-sm font-medium text-purple-900">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Entrer un motif" name="motif[]" id="motif[]" value="/">  //This is the input of the "motif".You can write if you want a motif to the student//
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">      
                             <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  name="students[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $student->id }}" id="student-{{ $student->id }}" />    //This is my checkbox, everything work correctly.It correctly attach the boolean with the student into my pivot table
                            </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody> 
                   
                    @endforeach
```

Im sure it is something to deal with the controller.

It suppose to create something like this when I save the appel :

"
All the things I need is to request the input "motif" and be saved like the image.My form is in the image too

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXh6b.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5X7F.png

Answer (score 0):

In your `Apple` model

```
public function minorstudents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class);
}
```

To set the `motif` for all the students you need to loop over each of the coming `minorstudents` values in the request **BUT you must make the `motif` input name attribute such as `motif[]`** because you give this input a `motif` and this is invalid

```
$appel = Appel::create(["createur" => $request->createur]);

foreach($request->minorstudents as $index => $minorstudent) {
    $appel->minorstudents()->attach($request->minorstudents, [
         "present" => true,
         "motif" => $request->input("motif")[$index]
    ]);
}

foreach(Minorstudent::whereNotIn("id")->get() as $index => $minorstudent) {
    $appel->minorstudents()->attach($minorstudent, [
         "motif" => $request->input("motif")[$index]
    ]);
}
```

Comment: public function appels(){
        return $this->BelongsToMany(Appel::class);
    } My table is correctly link to the pivot table.My problem is to add a data into the column motif into the pivot table

Comment: You must add `withPivot('motif')` at the end of the line as I have shown

Comment: Okay yes I added your code in my model "AppelStudent" but I dont know how to add the data "motif" from my input to the column "motif like with "$appel->students = $request->motif; or ? Thats my problem...I already had the code you sent me in my model...

Comment: Try this code `$appel->students()->attach(["motif" => "your_value"])`

Comment: So I tried this  $appel->students()->attach(["motif" =>$request->input('motif')]); and  $appel->students()->syncWithPivotValues([1, 2, 3, 4], ['motif' => $request->input('motif')]); but nothing appear in my collumn "motif" and it duplicate my data when I save everything in my form

Comment: I've updated the code, I wish it helps you :)

Comment: I am sorry but, what do you want is to attach the value of `motif` in the pivot table, it's true?

Comment: Yes I want to attach "motif" to the student if a "motif" is wrote

Comment: I've updated the code again to be suitable with your code as I tried this code and worked for me

Comment: I've update my first question I hope you get what I want but I think we are on the good way !

Comment: So your problem now is to save the `motif` if the student was in the class, it's true?

Comment: I updated my post again.I want to save the "motif" whenever it is check or not

Comment: Hmm..there is something that is NOT clear to me is why you attach the students that come in the request then attach the students that do NOT come in the request?. I think your problem is to assign each `motif` to its student So you can loop over each student then assign the `motif` to him.

Comment: Because my checkbox return 0 or 1 and I need to attach the student who are check (1) or not check (0) so I know which student was in class or not

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to attach the motif to the student at the same time

Comment: I wish the updates on the code helps you now ;)